# how to display gutenberg editor in a view

Tags: block-editor, editor

In a custom plugin, i display the content from a post in an editor like this

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

but when the content is done with gutenberg , i want to display the gutenberg editor and not the classic editor.
How can i do this ?
Thanks
Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i completely understand what you want to do... you want to use the block editor on an admin page of your page, but then use it to edit the content of an existing post?

I'm not quite sure if this can work as you intended. However, there IS an experimental way to include a seperate instance of the block editor on an admin page. Please use [this tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/tutorial/) on the wordpress developer portal to create this.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks , this is probably the documentation i was looking for. I'm buiding a translation tool Falang for WordPress and for post/pages  translation i display side by side the original and the translated. For gutenberg editor it was working but only with the classic editor display.

Comment: This tutorial don't seem to work , i was trying for testing to use a block editor in a settings page but other user has the same problem.